# Can't login from mobile chrome but works in mobile firefox

Tags: authentication, recaptcha, mobile-chrome

In my [site](https://www.monsoonmalabar.com/users/sign_in) I can login from all pc browsers and mobile firefox. But i can't login from mobile chrome, opera, or uc browser.

Login info:

username: testdemo

password: 123456

When I test in chrome remote device option in pc console I get,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 ()
```

and

```
www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v156307712k698/recaptcha__en.js:511 Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty
    at Object.Yp (www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1563777128698/recaptcha__en.js:511)
    at onloadCallback (<anonymous>:8:16)
    at Rn (www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1563777128698/recaptcha__en.js:520)
    at w3 (www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1563777128698/recaptcha__en.js:518)
    at www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1563777128698/recaptcha__en.js:524
    at www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1563777128698/recaptcha__en.js:544
```

**Edit**
My recaptcha file

```
<p class="alert lead alert-success">Free Blogging Platform - Sign Up</p>
<br /><br /><br />

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), class: "form-horizontal" ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :username, required: true, label_html: {class: "alert alert-success lead"}, autofocus: true, hint: 'no special characters, no numbers only letters [a-z]' %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, label_html: {class: "alert alert-success lead"}, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label_html: {class: "alert alert-success lead"}, required: true %>


    <div id="g-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcOGEgUAAAAAOxX4ImDmM_MNKUjmziUh_dd"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Create Blog", data: { disable_with: "This may take upto 2 minutes... "} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<!-- google recaptcha -->
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit' async defer></script>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<script>
  var captcha_interval;
  var myCallback=function(){
    document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].disabled=false;
  };
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].disabled=true;
    grecaptcha.render(
     document.getElementById('g-recaptcha'),
     {
       callback: myCallback,
       sitekey: "6LcOGEgUAAAXmBVg4ImDmM_MNKUjmziUh_dd"
     });
  };
</script>
```

In network header I got

```
utf8 tick mark
authenticity token: a token id
user[username]: testdemo
user[password]: 123456
user[remember me]: 0
commit: Log in
```

does this authenicity token is relates to recaptcha?

Comment: I googled HTTP 422 and it is 'unprocessable entity', basically meaning whatever the client sent is well formed and valid, but the actual request inside it isn't valid. So use F12 console to inspect what each browser is sending, and see what the difference in the chrome version

Comment: I don't know how to do that, do you have a link to guide. But here is some parts of network header ```Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.monsoonmalabar.om/users/sign_in" -Method "POST" -Headers @{"method"="POST"; "authority"="www.monsoonmalabar.com"; "scheme"="https"; "path"="/users/sign_in"; "pragma"="no-cache"; "cache-control"="no-cache"; "save-data"="on"; "upgrade-insecure-requests"="1"; "user-agent"=32yJ5kHN6bG5Dhg%3D%3D&user%5Busername%5D=testdemo&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456&user%5Bremember_me%5D=0&commit=Log+in"```. In this we can see that username is testdemo and pass is 123456

Comment: Any hint please...

Comment: Did you build this site from scratch or did you use some kind of template to do it? AKAIK this error is return by whatever is servicing the `https://www.monsoonmalabar.com/users/sign_in` URL - whats the server side code behind that?